# How to change the value of a scss variable that's imported from another file in order to achieve theming?

Tags: angular, sass, themes, scss-mixins

I have an Angular library of components, that uses a theme.scss file in order to implement a predefined theming system for my components using the following code.

```
$theme : light !default;

@mixin set-theme($new-theme){
  $theme: $new-theme !global;
}

$theme-colors:(
  light:(
    primary-color: cadetblue,
    secondary-color: white,
    font-color:white,
  ),
  dark:(
    primary-color: #3f3f9e,
    secondary-color: gray,
    font-color:gray,
  )
);

@function get-color($color,$theme: $theme){
  @return map-get(map-get($theme-colors,$theme),$color);
}
```

And then in my components, I use the get-color function in order to get the corresponding color from the value stored inside the $theme-colors map using the $theme global variable.

```
button{
  background-color: theme.get-color(primary-color);
  color: theme.get-color(font-color);
  border:1px solid theme.get-color(secondary-color);
}
```

In another Angular application, I imported with @use, the theme.scss file inside te styles.scss file and then I used the set-theme mixin from the code above to try and change the $theme variable as follows:

```
@include theme.set-theme("dark");
```

The expected behavior would be that when I use my components from the library inside my Angular application, the "dark" color scheme should be applied, but instead they still use the default "light" theme.

So, why my components don't update?

If this is the wrong approach of achieving theming inside an Angular library please let me know what the right one would be.